# How to put modal dialog in fullscreen mode using react?

Tags: reactjs

I have to display an element in full screen mode on clicking a button. This works. However, it doesn't render the modal dialog in full screen mode. This is because this modal dialog is an element that is added at the other div named modal_root and this content div is not rendered in dom. How can I make sure that this modal dialog is also rendered in full screen mode?

Below is the code,

```
<body>
    <div id="root">
        <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

On clicking on the fullscreen button i call the below method.

```
open_content_fullscreen = () => {
    let elem = document.querySelector('.content');
    if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
        elem.requestFullscreen();
    }
}
```

Now when i click some button say "edit" it opens the modal dialog which is the element that is rendered at the div with class modal_root and content div is not seen in the dom something like below,

```
<body>
    <div id="root">
        <div class="modal_root">
            <div class="dialog"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

How can i fix this. could someone help me with this. Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by `it opens the modal dialog which is the element that is rendered at the other div` ?

Comment: i have edited the question. also i mean that the modal dialog when its rendered the div with content class is not seen in dom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When interacting with the DOM directly from a React component, you'll typically want to do so via a `ref`.

This means that you should call `requestFullscreen()` via the DOM element provided by a component `ref`, rather than the result returned from `querySelector()`.

So for instance, you could refactor your code to follow a pattern like this:

```
/* An example "root component" */
class RootComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    /* Create a ref to the div that we want to access DOM element of */
    this.fullscreenModal = React.createRef();
  }

  openContentFullscreen = () => {    
      /* let elem = document.querySelector('.content'); */

      /* Access the element of "full screen" div: */
      const elem = this.fullscreenModal.current;

      /* Interact with it as a normal DOM element: */
      if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
          elem.requestFullscreen();
      }
  }

  render() {

      return <div>
        <button onClick={this.openContentFullscreen}>Open Fullscreen</button>

        <div ref={this.fullscreenModal}>
            Hello fullscreen world!
        </div>
      </div>
  }
}
```

For more information on `refs`, [see this documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#creating-refs) - hope that helps!